# Return False or True

Tags: java, booleano

Preciso saber se o segundo numero é múltiplo do primeiro número, se sim retornar `true` caso contrario `false`, não estou conseguindo declarar a biblioteca `Boolean`.

```
package br.fatec.com;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Mult {
    

    public static void main(String args[]){
        
        Scanner numero1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("digite o primeiro numero");
        
        Scanner numero2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("digite o segundo numero");
       
        
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        int mult;
        
        mult = (num2 % num1);
      
     boolean verifiva int mult; {
            if (mult >=0){
                   return True;
            }else
                   return False;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 1):

O código todo não parece fazer sentido. Está criando dois leitores, não está lendo nada, está fora de ordem, depois declara variáveis que não usa, aí vem várias coisas completamente sem sentido, e fala em biblioteca Boolean que é um tipo de dado. Sugiro procurar uma forma estruturada para aprender.

Para saber se um número é múltiplo de outro tem que saber se o resto da divisão entre eles é 0. E só, È simples assim:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Mult {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner leitor = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("digite o primeiro numero");
        int numero1 = leitor.nextInt();
        System.out.println("digite o segundo numero");
        int numero2 = leitor.nextInt();
        System.out.println(numero2 % numero1 == 0 ? "É múltiplo" : "Não é múltiplo");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/FYmpab). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hcbontfo-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Multiple.java).

Answer (score 0):

Seu código não tem muita lógica, para fazer esse exercício basta você pensar no resto da divisão, caso o resto da divisão do primeiro pelo segundo for zero então é múltiplo.

```
public class NumeroMultiplo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numero1 =Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o numero 1 "));
    int numero2 =Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o numero 2 "));
    boolean comparacao;

    if(numero1 % numero2 == 0) {
        comparacao = true;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Numero é multiplo - "+comparacao);
    } else {
        comparacao = false;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não é multiplo - " +comparacao);
    }

 }

}
```